# Set default date in OpenERP

Tags: odoo

I'm working at creating a module for OpenERP 7 to set Today's Date as default value when creating a new Partner. I've installed the module, restarted the Openerp service and defaults aren't changed a bit. *(I'd included a "goofball" field and bogus default data for the website field to make sure it's not a python lambda code problem. It wasn't...)* Here's my code in partner.py:

```
from osv import osv, fields
import datetime

class res_partner(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'

    _columns = {"goofball":fields.char('goofball', size=15)}

    _defaults = {
        'website': 'www.veppsight.com',
        'date': lambda *a: datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
    }
```

The default data isn't entered for the website & date fields and the "goofball" field isn't create in the database which I verified in psql. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you updated the module?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since V6.1 there is a new function to deal with today's date, called context_today.

You can check background on this at the following link...
http://openerp-expert-framework.71550.n3.nabble.com/Bug-925361-Re-6-1-date-values-that-are-initialized-as-defaults-may-appear-as-quot-off-by-one-day-quoe-td3741270.html

Based on that, you can just use...

```
_ defaults = { 
'date1': fields.date.context_today, 
}
```

Regards,
-Mario

Answer (score 2):

Import time and In the defaults

```
_defaults = {
    'website': 'www.veppsight.com',
    'date': lambda *a: time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
}
```

Comment: then how to get date-1 as default.?
can we use fields.date.context_today-1  ? or another ease way

Answer (score 1):

Use following code :

```
from osv import osv, fields
import time

class res_partner(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'

    _columns = {"goofball":fields.char('goofball', size=15)}

    _defaults = {
        'website': 'www.veppsight.com',
        'date1': time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
    }
```

AND IF POSSIBLE RENAME FIELD NAME `DATE` TO SOMETHING ELSE. AS DATE IS DT IN POSTGRESQL

Thank You

Comment: Thanks for replying, firebug. I wish I could say it works now, but behavior is just the same as it was before. I'll keep researching... Any other comments are more than welcome.

Comment: Ok, my mistake. I'd forgotten to import partner in the __init__.py file! But your suggestion to use time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') does also work so I'll accept your answer, firebug.

Comment: Are you sure this solution doesn't make the default equal to the date the server was started, and this code first evaluated? I bet if you test it tomorrow, the default will be today.

Comment: @PhilFrost: :O That is why it is called Today !! I guess.

Comment: @firebug: well, the problem isn't so much `today()`, it's that the `time.strftime` here is evaluated when the module is imported, not when a new object is created. It might as well be `'date1': '2013-01-03'`. I'm guessing, but I bet this is the reason some of these solutions have `lambda *a: ...` in them; this makes an anonymous function, the contents of which are evaluated when the function is called, not when the module is imported.

Answer (score 1):

```
_defaults = {
        'date': lambda self,cr,uid,context={}: context.get('date', fields.date.context_today(self,cr,uid,context=context)),
```

or

```
'date': lambda self, cr, uid, context={}: context.get('date', time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")),
```

or

```
'date' : fields.date.context_today,
 }
```

Lambda is a in line or anonymous function in python.

Comment: for days deduction how to do.?
syntax : 
'date_of_birth':lambda *a: (datetime.today() + timedelta(days=(5))).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
from osv import osv, fields
import time

class res_partner(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'

    _columns = {"goofball": fields.char('goofball', size=15)}

    _defaults = {
        'website': 'www.veppsight.com',
        'date1': lambda *a: time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
    }


res_partner()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, Phil. I was verifying the field by directly querying the database, rather than making a view for a bogus definition that I'd intended only to test. Also, the class did need to be instantiated, which wasn't in the original post. My mistake there. Thanks for mentioning it, though for any other readers.

Comment: @Phil If you want discussion on this, please start new thread, do not mix all here.